# SQL COUNT by each date with multiple date fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have the following table and query which is not giving the correct result.

JOB table have Open, Finished and Closed dates.

Now I need to pull the count of Open, Finished and Closed Jobs between on the selected dates group by each dates and Location.

Please help me to get the result like in below expected result

```
+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+
| JOB_id| DateOpen  | DateFinish | DateClose | Location |
+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+
|   100 | 16-Dec-18 | 18-Dec-18  | 19-Dec-18 | A        |
|   101 | 16-Dec-18 | 18-Dec-18  | 19-Dec-18 | A        |
|   102 | 17-Dec-18 | 19-Dec-18  | 20-Dec-18 | C        |
|   103 | 10-Dec-18 | 11-Dec-18  | 16-Dec-18 | D        |
|   104 | 17-Dec-18 | 19-Dec-18  | 18-Dec-18 | E        |
+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT count(DateOpen) as Opened,
       count(DateFinish) as Finised,
      count(DateClose) as Closed,
      (DateOpen) as Date 
FROM JOBS
WHERE DateOpen BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/17/2018')
group by DateOpen
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+-----------+------+----------+--------+----------+
|   Date    | Open | Finished | Closed | Location |
+-----------+------+----------+--------+----------+
| 16-Dec-18 |    2 |        0 |      0 | A        |
| 16-Dec-18 |    0 |        0 |      1 | D        |
| 17-Dec-18 |    1 |        0 |      0 | C        |
| 17-Dec-18 |    1 |        0 |      0 | E        |
+-----------+------+----------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: What is current output?

Comment: Can you paste the query to generate data

Comment: How can I distinguish  JOB_id 101 and 102 by its state ? Both have a same date in DateFinished and DateClosed

Comment: Why are your date columns not yet of type DATE?

Comment: @SalmanA BETWEEN

Comment: Why you get _0 Open_ for the 2nd _16-Dec-18_?

Comment: @Sami : for Location "D"

Answer (score 2):

You could pull all open, finish and closed dates in a single column and left join your jobs table with it:

```
DECLARE @date1 AS DATE = '2018-12-16';
DECLARE @date2 AS DATE = '2018-12-17';

WITH dates(date) AS (
    SELECT DateOpen FROM jobs
    UNION
    SELECT DateFinish FROM jobs
    UNION
    SELECT DateClose FROM jobs
)
SELECT dates.date
     , Location
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN dates.date = DateOpen THEN 1 END) AS Opened
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN dates.date = DateFinish THEN 1 END) AS Finished
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN dates.date = DateClose THEN 1 END) AS Closed
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN jobs ON dates.date IN (DateOpen, DateFinish, DateClose)
WHERE dates.date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2
GROUP BY dates.date
       , Location
```

Result:

```
| date       | Location | Opened | Finished | Closed |
|------------|----------|--------|----------|--------|
| 16/12/2018 | A        | 2      | 0        | 0      |
| 16/12/2018 | D        | 0      | 0        | 1      |
| 17/12/2018 | C        | 1      | 0        | 0      |
| 17/12/2018 | E        | 1      | 0        | 0      |
```

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d49a04b8d0fc0fc270ec1d11c1c43612)

Comment: Your query pulls the data correctly  but take long time to load as i have one million rows

Comment: Do you have any indexes created on the table?

Comment: There is an implicit conversion occurring i feel

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query for the desired result set.

```
select coalesce(t1.date, t2.date, t3.date) as date, t1.Opened, t2.Finished, t3.Closed,
coalesce(t1.location, t2.location, t3.location) as location
from
(SELECT Convert(date,DateOpen) as Date ,count(JobID) as Opened, location      
FROM JOBS
WHERE DateOpen BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/17/2018')
group by Convert(date,DateOpen), location 
) t1
Full join 
(SELECT Convert(date,DateFinish) as Date ,count(JobID) as Finished, location      
FROM JOBS
WHERE DateFinish BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/17/2018')
group by Convert(date,DateFinish), location 
) t2  ON(t1.date = t2.date and t1.location = t2.location)
FULL JOIN
(SELECT Convert(date,DateClose) as Date ,count(JobID) as Closed, location      
FROM JOBS
WHERE DateClose BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/17/2018')
group by Convert(date,DateClose), location 
) t3  ON(t2.date = t3.date and t2.location = t3.location)
```

Comment: Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend you to stop storing dates as text and use proper data types.

To do what you need, make a list of all dates and locations by selecting each of the dates columns and location and union them into one result (first cte - allDates). Then we need a distinct list (second cte - aggregated) to select from, and count the number of rows from your table that match the current date/location values.

Here is the whole solution:

```
declare @JOBS table(JOB_ID int, DateOpen varchar(10), DateFinish varchar(10), DateClose varchar(10), Location varchar(5))
insert into @JOBS values
(   100, '16-Dec-18', '18-Dec-18', '19-Dec-18', 'A'),
(   101, '16-Dec-18', '18-Dec-18', '19-Dec-18', 'A'),
(   102, '17-Dec-18', '19-Dec-18', '20-Dec-18', 'C'),
(   103, '10-Dec-18', '11-Dec-18', '16-Dec-18', 'D'),
(   104, '17-Dec-18', '19-Dec-18', '18-Dec-18', 'E')

;with allDates as (
select convert(date, DateOpen) as [Date], Location from @JOBS
union
select convert(date, DateFinish), Location from @JOBS
union
select convert(date, DateClose), Location from @JOBS
),
aggregated as (
    select [Date], Location
    from allDates
    group by [Date], Location
)
select
    a.Date
    , (select count(*) from @JOBS where a.[Date] = DateOpen and a.Location = Location) [Open]
    , (select count(*) from @JOBS where a.[Date] = DateFinish and a.Location = Location) Finished
    , (select count(*) from @JOBS where a.[Date] = DateClose and a.Location = Location) Closed
    , Location
from aggregated a
where a.Date between '20181216' and '20181217'
```

Comment: Then why do you convert them to date, e.g. `group by Convert(date,DateOpen)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement with sum,

```
    SELECT  Convert(date,DateOpen) as Date ,      
           sum(case when DateOpen =DateOpen then 1 else 0 end) as Opened,
           sum(case when DateFinish=DateOpen then 1 else 0 end) as Finised,
           sum(case when DateClose=DateOpen then 1 else 0 end) as Closed,
           Location

    FROM JOBS
    WHERE DateOpen BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/17/2018')
    group by Convert(date,DateOpen),Location

    UNION

    SELECT  Convert(date,DateClose) as Date ,      
           sum(case when DateOpen =DateClose then 1 else 0 end) as Opened,
           sum(case when DateFinish=DateClose then 1 else 0 end) as Finised,
           sum(case when DateClose=DateClose then 1 else 0 end) as Closed,
           Location

    FROM JOBS
    WHERE DateClose BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/16/2018')
    group by Convert(date,DateClose),Location
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code, using `SUM` function that sums the state of processes on inputed dates:

```
SELECT Convert(date1,DateOpen) as Date,
       sum(case
            when DateOpen = Convert(date1,DateOpen) then 1
            else 0
           end) as Open,
       sum(case
            when DateFinish = Convert(date1,DateOpen) then 1
            else 0
           end) as Finished,
      sum(case
            when DateClose = Convert(date1,DateOpen) then 1
            else 0
           end) as Closed,
      Location
FROM JOBS
group by Location
UNION ALL  
SELECT Convert(date2,DateOpen) as Date,
       sum(case
            when DateOpen = Convert(date2,DateOpen) then 1
            else 0
           end) as Open,
       sum(case
            when DateFinish = Convert(date2,DateOpen) then 1
            else 0
           end) as Finished,
      sum(case
            when DateClose = Convert(date2,DateOpen) then 1
            else 0
           end) as Closed,
      Location
FROM JOBS
group by Location;
```

> EDITED: `date1` and `date2` are input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '12/16/2018'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '12/17/2018'

SELECT 
  count(CASE when DateOpen BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 end) as Opened,
  count(CASE when DateFinish BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 end) as Finised,
  count(CASE when DateClose BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate THEN 1 end) as Closed,
  DateOpen as Date,
  Location
FROM JOBS
WHERE DateOpen BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
group by DateOpen, Location
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try using unpivot to see how the performance is

```
with cols_to_rows
  as (
      select *
        from t
      unpivot(col for val in (dateopen,datefinish,dateclose))m 
      )
select col
       ,location 
       ,count(case when val='dateopen' then 1 end)   as open1
       ,count(case when val='datefinish' then 1 end) as finish
       ,count(case when val='dateclose' then 1 end)  as close1
  from cols_to_rows
where col between cast('2018-12-16' as date)
  and cast('2018-12-17' as date)
group by col,location,val
order by col,location


| 10/12/2018 00:00:00 | D | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 11/12/2018 00:00:00 | D | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 16/12/2018 00:00:00 | A | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 16/12/2018 00:00:00 | D | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 17/12/2018 00:00:00 | C | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 17/12/2018 00:00:00 | E | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 18/12/2018 00:00:00 | A | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 18/12/2018 00:00:00 | E | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 19/12/2018 00:00:00 | A | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 19/12/2018 00:00:00 | C | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 19/12/2018 00:00:00 | E | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 20/12/2018 00:00:00 | C | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

Here is a dbfiddle link

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=1ca0c0180a4d31d6e112e9f3b1b99715

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '12/16/2018',
            @MaxDate DATE = '12/17/2018'


    DECLARE @DateTable TABLE (DateOpen DATETIME)

    INSERT INTO @DateTable
    SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
            Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate)
    FROM    sys.all_objects a
            CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;

    ;with cte
    As
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT d.DateOpen, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN j.DateOpen =d.DateOpen THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(partition by d.DateOpen,Location) As [Open]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN j.DateFinish =d.DateOpen THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(partition by d.DateOpen,Location) As [Finished]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN j.DateClose =d.DateOpen THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(partition by d.DateOpen,Location) As [Closed]
        ,Location
        FROM @DateTable d
        CROSS JOIN JOBS j   
    )

    Select * from cte where [Open]>0 or Finished>0 or Closed>0
    Order by DateOpen,Location
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT Location
FROM T
GROUP BY Location
) L CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT DateOpen
  FROM T
  WHERE DateOpen BETWEEN '2018-12-16' AND '2018-12-18'
) D
GROUP BY Location, DateOpen
),
 F AS
(
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM T WHERE Location = CTE.Location AND DateOpen = CTE.DateOpen) [Open],
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM T WHERE Location = CTE.Location AND DateFinish = CTE.DateOpen)[Finish],
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM T WHERE Location = CTE.Location AND DateClose = CTE.DateOpen) [Close]
FROM CTE
)
SELECT DateOpen,
       [Open],
       [Finish],
       [Close],
       Location
FROM F
WHERE [Open] > 0
      OR
      [Finish] > 0
      OR
      [Close] > 0
ORDER BY DateOpen
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------------------+------+--------+-------+----------+
|      DateOpen       | Open | Finish | Close | Location |
+---------------------+------+--------+-------+----------+
| 16/12/2018 00:00:00 |    2 |      0 |     0 | A        |
| 16/12/2018 00:00:00 |    0 |      0 |     1 | D        |
| 17/12/2018 00:00:00 |    1 |      0 |     0 | C        |
| 17/12/2018 00:00:00 |    1 |      0 |     0 | E        |
+---------------------+------+--------+-------+----------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=28d84888046f5112f1ba5adb97907ad3)**